# What does "__fips_constseg" means in openssl

Tags: openssl

In openssl C code, (aes_core.c, set_key.c, spr.h and so on) there is "__fips_constseg".

I don't know "__fips_constseg" means.

What's the role of it? Is it assembly code?

the source code is below:

---

#include < openssl/crypto.h >

#include "des_locl.h"

OPENSSL_IMPLEMENT_GLOBAL(int,DES_check_key,0)   /* defaults to false */

**__fips_constseg**

static const unsigned char odd_parity[256]={};

---

Comment: How did you find about this? Did you get some linker error or undefined reference of it?

Comment: To dbasic, I don't have any error but i'm curious about the meaning and the role of "__fips_constseg".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OpenSSL source code:

[`crypto/crypto.h`](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=crypto/crypto.h;hb=5ae8d6bcbaff99423a2608559d738a3fcf7ed6dc)

```c
#if defined(OPENSSL_FIPSCANISTER)
# include <openssl/fipssyms.h>
#else
# define __fips_constseg
#endif
```

[`fips/fipssyms.h`](http://git.openssl.org/gitweb/?p=openssl.git;a=blob;f=fips/fipssyms.h;hb=5ae8d6bcbaff99423a2608559d738a3fcf7ed6dc)

```c
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
# pragma const_seg("fipsro$b")
# pragma const_seg()
# define __fips_constseg __declspec(allocate("fipsro$b"))
#else
# define __fips_constseg
#endif
```

The `__fips_constseg` constant thus is only defined to a value, if

- `OPENSSL_FIPSCANISTER` is defined and
- the code is compiled using the Microsoft C compiler (which can be detected by the defined `_MSC_VER` constant).

Then, the code marked with that constant is placed in the constant data segment named `fipsro$b` (see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bkb2w6t.aspx) on the `allocate` specifier for details).

If any of the conditions above is not met, `__fips_constseg` is defined to nothing and thus the variables marked with that constant are put in the data segment they would normally be located in.